# Use lualatex in mathplotlib without pgf backend

Tags: matplotlib, latex

basically the title is the question:

I would like to use lualatex for all the text handling in a matplotlib plot without using the pgf backend.

I need fontenc package and customized fonts to have identical fonts in plots and in my latex documents but do not want to use the pgf backend.

Is there a hidden option somewhere?

The context is the following: I have a `mycommands.sty` file where all my defind `\newcommand` for math are stored. I use some specific fonts for, e. g., `\mathscr{p}`, which is not possible (small letter) without the `fontenc` package.

Now I want to use these custom commands in different places (legend, labels, title, ...) in the plot and have them **work** and **look exactly the same** as in the document I write and compile with lualatex.

The only point why it is not possible is that matplotlib internally uses pdflatex for the compilation which gives me errors when using `fontenc` and therefore some of my commands do not work.

Thanks.

Comment: LuaTex or latex -- which one is it? Also, would something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) be good enough? If not, please give us some kind of example of what you actually have in mind.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Well, lualatex is an extra thing. The point is, that lualatex is able to use fontenc while pdflatex not. Your link is for the basic tex usage. I known them. This question is about **which tex to use to generate the labels, text, ...** in a plot when using **tex**.

Comment: I have edited the question and provided some more information.